# react + typescript, how to distinguish exported and internal props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, react-intl

consider the following component:

```
interface OProps {
  // property here should be sent by parent
  id: string;
}

interface IProps {
  // property here just use internal for intellisense
  notNeed: number;
}

export class Foo extends React.Component<OProps & IProps, void> {}

export class Bar extends React.Component<OProps & InejctedIntlProps, void> {}
```

When I use `Foo` component, It should send both OProps and IProps...

```
// error: 'notNeed' is missing
const f = <Foo id="test" />;

// error: 'intl' is missing
const b = <Bar id="test" />;
```

IProps maybe in `injectedIntlProps`, hoc injected props, mobx store props, or any props that not need inject by the parent.

I know there is some way to solve it, for example:

`export default injectedIntlProps<OProps>` (I do not prefer export default...) or declare props as partial `notNeed?: number`, but still wondering is there a better solution? only export needful props...

Comment: Did you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly you're using a connected/container component within some parent component, and you wish to differentiate between mapped props (props from the redux store) and own props (props that are passed in from the parent component).

You're on the right track by splitting your properties up into separate interfaces, you just need to specify which props are mapped and which props are own props in the connect function.

Here is an example of how to do this for your foo component. Note that you've omitted quite a few key parts of your component so I've had to make a few assumptions.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
// import {IAppState} from '../AppState';

interface IOwnProps {
  id: string;
}

interface IMappedProps {
  notNeed: number;
}

export interface IFooProps extends IMappedProps, IOwnProps { }

export class Foo extends React.Component<IFooProps, void> {}

// This function is just an example, yours may look different.
function mapStateToProps(state: IAppState): IMappedProps {
    return {
        notNeed: state.notNeed,
    };
}

export default connect<IMappedProps, null, IOwnProps>(mapStateToProps, null,
)(Foo);
```

If I have missed the mark and you're not using a connecting component, then you simply need to use the components internal state.

e.g.

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface IProps {
  id: string;
}

interface IState {
  notNeed: number;
}

export class Foo extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {}
```

Comment: Not certain that answer solves the issue as I understood it. It seems like above the goal was to be able to write something like 
`const b = <Bar id="test" />;` and have typescript okay with the fact that you're not passing `intl`, a required prop into the component, as it is being injected in the export statement, eg `export default injectIntl(Bar);`. Did you have any thoughts about this approach? I've run into the same issue in my app; Using `<Bar intl={undefined} />` will compile, but it seems incorrect. Also, you cannot mark intl as optional, as extending InjectedIntlProps requires intl.